# Convergence of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for Uniformly Form-Bounded Operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that $A$ is an operator on a dense domain $D(A)\subset L^2$ with compact resolvent, and with quadratic form $q(f,g):=\langle f,Ag\rangle$.

---

Let $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of quadratic forms on $D(A)$ that are *uniformly form-bounded* by $A$, in the sense that there exists $0<\alpha<1$ and $\beta>0$ independent of $n$ such that
$$|r_n(f,f)|\leq \alpha\cdot q(f,f)+\beta\cdot\|f\|_2,\qquad f\in D(A).$$
Since $\alpha<1$ the operators $A_n$ defined by the form $q+r_n$ all have compact resolvent.

---

Suppose that the $r_n$ have a limit $r_\infty$, in the sense that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n(f,f)\to r_\infty(f,f)$$
for every $f\in D(A)$. Define the operator $A_\infty$ through the form $q+r_\infty$. Clearly
$$|r_\infty(f,f)|\leq \alpha\cdot q(f,f)+\beta\cdot\|f\|_2,\qquad f\in D(A),$$
and thus $A_\infty$ has compact resolvent as well.

> **Question.** Does the uniform form-bound of the $r_n$ give rise to a *dominated convergence*-type result for the spectrum of $A_n$, that is, the eigenvalues of $A_n$ converge to that of $A_\infty$, and the eigenfunctions converge in $L^2$?